# Show that $\left\{ f_{n}\right\}$ converges pointwise on $E$ to a function $f$ that is finite a.e. on $E$.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $\left\{ f_{n}\right\}$  be an increasing sequence of nonnegative measurable function on $E$. Suppose there is a number $M>0$ such that $\left|\int_{E}f_{n}\right|\leq M$ for all $n$. Show that $\left\{ f_{n}\right\}$  converges pointwise on $E$ to a function $f$ that is finite a.e. on $E$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{E}f_{n}=\int_{E}f.$

I think I only have to show that $\{f_n\}$ converges pointwise to $f$, since I can use MCT for the second part. In order to show the convergence, I have to show that for each $\epsilon>0$, for each $x\in E$, there exist $N$ such that $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $n>N$. This is the part where I actually dont know how to show. So, how can I use the given in order to proceed?

Comment: you don't need absolute values in the second line

Answer (score 2):

The pointwise limit $f$ surely exists as a measurable function from $E$ to $[0,+\infty]$ as pointwise we have an increasing real sequence that converges to its supremum.

You only have to argue that $A=\{x: f(x)=+\infty\}$ has measure $0$. If you've done that MCT (e.g. as given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem), will do the rest.

So suppose it has not, and deduce a contradiction with the existence of $M$, bounding the integrals of the $f_n$.

Basic idea: If $\mu(A) > 0$ then certainly $f_n(x) > \frac{2M}{\mu(A)}$ for $x \in A$ and $n$ large enough, and then

$$\int_E f_n \,d\mu \ge \int_A f_n \,d\mu \ge \mu(A) \cdot \frac{2M}{\mu(A)}=2M$$

which would give a contradiction.
Minor issue: as convergence is pointwise we can achieve the desired lower bound for $f_n$ only for a subset of $A$ (but these subsets have measures converging to $\mu(A)$). So some extra argumentation for that is needed.

Comment: Thank you @Henno. Why does the pointwise limit $f$ surely exists?

Comment: @FlickerBeat every $f_n(x)$ for fixed $x$ is either bounded and then it converges to the supremum or its unbounded and converges to $+\infty$. So being monotonous and standard properties of the reals tell us this.

Comment: Thank you @Henno.

Answer (score 0):

$f_n$ converges (by monotonicity) to an extended real valued measurable function $f$. Fatou's Lemma shows that $\int f \leq \lim \inf \int f_n \leq M <\infty$.  This implies that $f$ is finite a.e. on $E$ and Monotone Convergence Theorem gives $\lim \int_E f_n =\int_E f$.

Comment: Thank you @kavi. However, I need clarification on this part "$f_n$ converges (by monotonicity) to an extended real valued measurable function  $f$". Does it say that every monotone sequence of function converges?

Comment: In measure theory one is not afraid of $\pm \infty$! Yes, every monotone sequence converges in the extended real line. The limit of an increasing sequence is simply the supremum (which may be $\infty$ ).

Comment: Thanks, I get it now.